# Use gradle for Android/Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I would like to use gradle for my Android/Eclipse project because I want to be able to install a development version of my app next to the released version (as seen here: [What is a practical way to install stable and development app versions simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697691/what-is-a-practical-way-to-install-stable-and-development-app-versions-simultane))

Using the command line for doing so is OK for me.

So I moved the src folder of my project to src/main/java and created a `build.gradle` file (as described here: http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/Make-Android-Eclipse-project-ready-for-Android-Studio):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

But when I run `gradle build`, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
...
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

I already found that error on stackoverflow. Some people say it's because of using the wrong version of gradle. ([Gradle is issuing an error "Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811514/gradle-is-issuing-an-error-could-not-create-plugin-of-type-appplugin))

My questions:

- As far as I understand, this version number in build.gradle (0.12.+) is the version of the gradle plugin and not of gradle itself. How can I find out which gradle plugin version I'm using?
- And where does this plugin come from? Is it part of the gradle installation? Or part part of Eclipse? Or of ADT?
- I installed Gradle IDE as Eclipse plugin. Does it interfere with a regular gradle installation?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, finally I succeeded compiling my app with gradle.

Just in case somebody else has the same problem, here is what I did:

- Right click your Android project in Eclipse -> Export -> Android -> Generate Gradle build files.
- This creates `build.gradle`, `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat` and `settings.gradle` (in my case some levels above my project). Don't move these files into your project folder.
- Then run `./gradlew build`. This will download the gradle plugin automatically (afaik) and create three apk's in `[PROJECT FOLDER]/build/outputs/apk`.

Comment: Id suggest you simple move to Android Studio and use Gradle as well. The latest Android Gradle plugin is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2` and use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.